# tomcat 6 vs tomcat7 performance in centos

Tags: tomcat

We currently have 4 production servers running servlets on tomcat6 behind an http accelerator. Are there any serious performance optimizations between tomcat 6 and 7? Are there any enhancements related to bytecode from using java 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The honest answer is: it depends on your configuration. Tomcat7 may be faster at some things. It is newer code, and I would expect it to offer some improvements, and in my experience it does. And again, depending on your application, Java 7 may offer you some improvements. It will be hard for anyone without more knowledge of your application to really answer this.
We found that one of the bigger benefits of moving to Java 7 was improved garbage collection and tuning options.